# Diophantine equations which are easier to solve using $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ compared to $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, contest-math, online-resources

I wanted to know applications of arithmetic in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ that helps in some problems of $\mathbb{Z}$. I found a wonderful set of [notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/ugradnumthy/Zinotes.pdf) by Keith Conrad. Now I want to read more on a similar topic. I find the generalizations of integers very interesting.

I am looking for some resource on math 'contest' type diophantine equations that can be solved by clever tricks in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}]$. What are some good resources on these type of problems?

Thanks guys!